# QPrinter printing misaligned with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, printing

I am developing a program to manage inventory and make sales with Qt, I am trying to print a sales receipt but only start printing from almost half the paper

```
    settings.beginGroup("Geral");
    QString nomeEmpresa = settings.value("nomeEmpresa").toString();
    QString cnpj = settings.value("cnpj").toString();
    settings.endGroup();

    QString content = "<b>" + nomeEmpresa + "</b><br/>" + cnpj + "<br/>"
                      "<br/><hr style='border: 1px solid #000000;'/>"
                      "<br/><table><thead><tr><th>Quantidade</th><th>Produto</th></tr></thead>"
                      "<tbody>";

    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
        content.append("<tr><td>" + QString::number(items.value(i).quantidade) + "</td><td>" + items.value(i).produto.codigoVenda() + "</td></tr>");
    }

    content.append("</tbody></table><br/><br/><br/><b>Obrigado pela preferência. Volte sempre</b>");

    //QString content = "Teste de alinhamento da impressao";

    QTextDocument doc;
    doc.setHtml(content);

    QPrinter printer;
    printer.setResolution(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);

    QPrintDialog dlgImpressao(&printer);
    if(dlgImpressao.exec() == QPrintDialog::Accepted){
        doc.print(&printer);
    }
```

On the left side a receipt from a supermarket of my city, on the right side the receipt Qt is printing

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9p69.png)

I would like it to be printed in the same way as the example on the left but I am not getting any advances

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the pages margins with `QPrinter::setPageMargins()`?

Comment: How are the printer default margins ?

Comment: @RickPat I just tried `printer.setPageMargins(QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0));` and still the same

Comment: @Samuel Try negative values.

Comment: I do not know what's happening but I changed the place code and it worked as it should but the printer did not stop ejecting paper